# mouseover on a block

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is something like this!

when I mouseover on '?' a block will appear with hyperlink of link & video.Now mouseover function should work until I enter into the block.When I move the crusor from the block/from the ?, then mouseout event should occur. As I'm a newbie to javascript I don't have much idea on this.Any examples on this pls

EDITED: Added actual code:

```
<apex:outputLink styleClass="helpLink" onmouseover="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display ='block';"> 
<apex:image value="/s.gif" styleClass="helpIcon" /></apex:outputLink>
<apex:outputPanel id="Foo" styleClass="video" >
    <a href="" target="_blank" onmouseout="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'none';" >link</a> 
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assume is correct actually. I guess you want direct code on this event processes. It is enough to bind events to your block element, such as:

```
$('#myTarget').bind('mouseover', function() { $(this).html('over'); });
$('#myTarget').bind('mouseout', function() { $(this).html('out'); });
```

Here is the link for jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hDvaB/

Comment: `<apex:page >
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery)}"/>
 <script>
     $('#myTarget').bind('mouseover',function() {
     alert('hi');
         $(this).html('Over');
     });
    
 </script>
 <style>
     #myTarget { 
     width:300px; height:200px; background: #ddd
     }
 </style>
 <apex:form >
     <div id='myTarget'></div>  
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>` If I use it in my salesforce org, over is not displaying.Don't know y?Help on this

Answer (score 0):

Put the HTML tag of the block inside the element that has the mouseover function.

To make this work, will need to define the position of your block absolute in relation to some parent element. The you just put the css attributes `top` and `left` to define where the block will appear in relation to the parent.

Try this.

Comment: I work on salesforce & my code is something like this `<apex:outputLink styleClass="helpLink" onmouseover="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'block';">  <apex:image value="/s.gif" styleClass="helpIcon" /></apex:outputLink><apex:outputPanel id="Foo" styleClass="video" ><a  href="" target="_blank" onmouseout="$('{!$Component.Foo}').style.display = 'none';" >link</a> </apex:outputPanel>`. here mouseover works fine when I place on link,and it doen't works when I place on block

Comment: As I don't have 10 Reputations I can't do it

Answer (score 0):

hover() can be better I think:

```
$("div").hover(function(){
$(this).html("in");},
 function(){
$(this).html("out");
 });
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/devWaleed/vQgMm/1/